# How do I change the AR camera so it displays in two images (stereo)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, google-cardboard, arcamera

I am developing a AR prototype in Unity that recognises targets and displays animated models on them. I want to use this prototype with google cardboard, therefore I need it to work in stereo camera.

I tried to change the **Device Type** in *AR camera inspector > Vuforia Engine Configuration > Digital Eyewear*, from ¨*handheld*¨ to ¨*phone + viewer¨.*
(I am following what is done in this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZzhXHqXM-g)

When I do this, everything stays the same (camera doesn´t change to stereo) and a black background called *Backgroundplane* shows up when I am in play mode, so I can´t see the real environment anymore.

Any ideas what may cause this or how could I do it differently?

Many thanks in advance!

Screenshots:

[Inspector ¨phone+viewer¨](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9ZRs.png)

[play mode Backgroundplane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z03xo.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved: the issue was in the player configuration.

I solved it following this path, I leave the link here for anyone with the same issue: https://medium.com/adventures-in-ar/converting-a-handheld-unity-vuforia-project-to-one-with-stereographic-view-on-a-headset-f646a7a86a11

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 empty game objects and name them Cam1 and Cam2.
Add a camera game object to both.
Settings for cameras.

Camera 1 (foreground):
Depth: 1
Clear flag: Depth only

Camera 2 (background):
Depth: 0
Clear Flag: Solid Color

Now just point camera 1 at the stuff you want in the foreground and point camera 2 at the background or whatever configuration you want.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering my question. I tried but as these are not AR cameras from Vuforia) so it doesn´t recognise the target. I tried replicating with the AR cameras but it stays the same.